# Use Refresh Token When Access Token is Expired

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, .net-core, authorization, coinbase-api

I'm using OAuth in .Net-Core 2.1 to Login to Coinbase, I've configured my authenticaton like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(COOKIE_AUTH)
    .AddCookie(options => options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60))
    .AddCoinbase(options => {
        options.SendLimitAmount = 1;
        options.SendLimitCurrency = "USD";
        options.SendLimitPeriod = SendLimitPeriod.day;
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientSecret"];
        COINBASE_SCOPES.ForEach(scope => options.Scope.Add(scope));
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:coinbase:avatar", "avatar_url");
    });
```

Using Postman I see that I'm getting an access token and a refresh token.   My token expires within two hours and never refreshes.

I know I can manually refresh the token, but I would expected this to be build into .net some where

Is there a way to refresh my token built into .net?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t make sense since the client is responsible for sending a valid token in order to expect the request to be authorized. When clients typically send tokens , they typically do so in a header. That header only contains a single access token, not a refresh token. Instead the refresh token is persisted at the client and used to get an access token that IS valid. Then it can make a different request and expect a different outcome. The flow is important.

Comment: Yeah but then how does .net core authenticate it’s users doesn’t it check that the token is still valid? Or does it only do that with oidc?

Comment: there is an expiration date on the token, If a request is made after the token is expired, the Authentication mechanism can use the refresh token to get a new access token.